# How can i know when the passed object/variable is referring to the same or different object

Tags: java, operators

There are two programs here . I am not able to understand the explanation of the problems as they have very contrasting explanations.

//Question1
What will be the output of the program?

```
class Test 
{
    static int s;
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        Test p = new Test();
        p.start();
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    void start() 
    {
        int x = 7;
        twice(x);
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }

    void twice(int x) 
    {
        x = x*2;
        s = x;
    }
}
    ans: 7 14
```

explanation: The int x in the twice() method is not the same int x as in the start() method. Start()'s x is not affected by the twice() method. The instance variable s is updated by twice()'s x, which is 14.
//ANOTHER QUESTION

````
```
    class Two 
    {
        byte x;
    }
    
    class PassO 
    {
        public static void main(String [] args) 
        {
            PassO p = new PassO();
            p.start();
        }
    
        void start() 
        {
            Two t = new Two();
            System.out.print(t.x + " ");
            Two t2 = fix(t);
            System.out.println(t.x + " " + t2.x);
        }
    
        Two fix(Two tt) 
        {
            tt.x = 42;
            return tt;
        }
    }
```

    ans= 0 42 42
````

explanation:
In the fix() method, the reference variable tt refers to the same object (class Two) as the t reference variable. Updating tt.x in the fix() method updates t.x (they are one in the same object). Remember also that the instance variable x in the Two class is initialized to 0.

Comment: You need to study the concept of variable's ***scope***.

Comment: i edited the question now could pls again go through it.

Comment: So as @PM77-1 said... you'd probably need to review how variable's scope work

And just a hint: Java parameter passing is pass-by-value (it means what you receive as a parameter in your method is a copy* of the argument passed on the method call) 

* a copy of the object if it is of a primitive type or a copy of the object reference if it is a more complex object

Comment: Also, one question at a time, please. Take the [tour] if you have not already.